# Blazor WASM standalone to ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with AAD B2C Authorization

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-6.0

I am building a Blazor WASM standalone UI that will use an existing ASP.NET Core 6 Web API for its backend. I have both the Blazor app and the Web API authenticating successfully to AAD B2C individually, but I can't get the UI to successfully pass the token to the API and always get a 401 from the API.

I'm referencing an NSWAG generated API Client from the Blazor app.

**Web API**

`appsettings.js`:

[image]

`Program.cs`:

[image]

**Blazor WASM Standalone**

`appsettings.js`:

[image]

`Program.cs`:

[image]

`Page.cs`:

[image]

`Service.cs`:

[image]

Comment: Instead of `images` please share your code in `code block`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving my issues with the help of this example: https://github.com/bryanknox/BlazorApiAadB2c/tree/main/BlazorSample

1. When newing up the `HttpClient`, I needed to add a custom `AuthorizationMessageHandler` and then configure the `authorizedUrls` and `scopes` since the UI is talking to an existing API with a different Base URL via a generated NSWAG client. I did this via an extension class.

[image]

2. From within `Program.cs`, I call the extension class like so: `builder.Services.AddApiClient(builder.Configuration);`
3. I also was using the GUID in the `.ConfigureHandler(scopes...` param URL, but actually needed to use it as it was defined within the B2C portal, which was with the actual API AAD B2C App Registration name.

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the Http 500 Error Initially. If the controller class has `RequiredScope` mentioned, remove that attribute.

- In client `appsettings.json` it has to be `Authority` and in Server `appsettingsjson` it has to be Instance.

***My WeatherForecastController.cs***

```cs
[RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAdB2C:Scopes")]
```

***My  appsettings.json from Client App***
`appsettings.json` file will be available under `wwwroot` folder

```cs
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Authority": "https://DomainInitialName.b2clogin.com/DomainInitialName.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Sign_In",
    "ClientId": "ClientID from Client AppRegistration",
    "ValidateAuthority": false
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

***Client Program.cs file***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using MySOBlazorApp.Client;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MySOBlazorApp.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("MySOBlazorApp.ServerAPI"));

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://DomainInitial.onmicrosoft.com/Client Id of Client App Registration  from Azure Portal/User Flow from the tenant");
});
await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

[image]

***My  appsettings.json from Server App***

```cs
{ 
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://DomainInitial.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "ClientID from Server AppRegistration",
    "Domain": "DomainInitial.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "UserFlow Name"
  },
 
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

***OutPut***
[image]

[image]

References taken from MSDoc [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Thanks, Harshitha, but it looks like your example is using a standard Blazor WASM App that is ASP.Net Core Hosted.  In my case, I have an existing Web API that I need to connect a new Blazor WASM app to, so they have different base addresses.

Comment: It is the Web API only. You can check my [controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EPSC.png) Action Method.